# How to float bootstrap column up if available

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a row with four containers, each col-md-6. Is there a way to position the third container such that it occupies the vertical space above it? I could make two columns, but the content of containers 2 and three could get large, so i would like the containers to rearrange based on the most efficient layout.

[Bootstrap Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0YRK.png)

```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="feature-content4 item-content">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="feature-content4 item-content">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="feature-content4 item-content">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="feature-content4 item-content">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: That's actually not an MCVE; you need to include a *complete* reproduction of your error. HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap linked. Stack Overflow provides a really nifty feature called Stack Snippets; you can create a runnable sandbox of code in your post, just like JSFiddle, CodePen, BootPly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really interesting problem. Pity that you did not write an example of the code. Maybe you should consider to rearrange container on two separate columns (like in the code below) but I hope someone can answer this question better than me.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="feature-content1 item-content">
                 ...
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="feature-content2 item-content">
                 ...  
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="feature-content3 item-content">
                  ... 
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="feature-content4 item-content">
                 ...
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I did end up going with something along the lines of what you have. I would have preferred to keep them free floating, but this is the next best solution :)